# Update a row in a data frame in R if one value is NA

Tags: r

I have the below data frame

```
Mor_Rate      Hospital Name
15.5             ABC
16               DEF
NA               GHI
```

I want to update the hospital Name to NA if the Mor_Rate contains NA.
Any simpler solution for this?

Thanks,
Pravellika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
  df$Hospital_Name[is.na(df$Mor_Rate) ] <- NA
```

or

```
  is.na(df$Hospital_Name) <- is.na(df$Mor_Rate)
  df
  # Mor_Rate Hospital_Name
  #1     15.5           ABC
  #2     16.0           DEF
  #3       NA          <NA>
```

If it is for the `row`

```
  df[is.na(df$Mor_Rate),] <- NA
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Mor_Rate = c(15.5, 16, NA), Hospital_Name = c("ABC", 
 "DEF", "GHI")), .Names = c("Mor_Rate", "Hospital_Name"), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I almost used the same as   df$Hospital_Name[is.na(df$Mor_Rate) ] <- NA except a small mistake by enclosing NA in double quotes and hence was getting an error. Thank you so much :)